# How to avoid caching for specific Nextjs API route?

Tags: caching, next.js, routes, vercel

I have nextjs api route `/api/auth/signout`, it basically just clears the specific cookie and send JSON back.

The problem is, when I deploy project in Vercel, this particular API working first time properly (cookie cleared and giving 200 response) but later it's not working (cookie not cleared and giving 304 response).

I want to know, is there any way to avoid cache only for this route?

What's the best possible way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this config on `next.config.js`

```
async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/<route-name>',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value: 'no-store, max-age=0',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
```

Comment: There's a warning against this here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#cache-control
"You cannot set Cache-Control headers in next.config.js file as these will be overwritten in production to ensure that API Routes and static assets are cached effectively."

Comment: Hi @AndreVitorio, thanks for the comment, if add 'cache-control' header in api route file will that only effect that particular route, or for all routes?

Comment: Hey @Shiva, I'm not sure but I believe only the specified route would be affected.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure `Cache-Control` header per API endpoint

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#cache-control

In your case, something like this might do the trick:

```js
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an answer to your use-case rather than the title of the question:

I think you should view the signout http endpoint as one that has a side-effect i.e. the destruction of a user session (even though nothing may be happening server-side). For http endpoints that have side-effects, it’s recommended to call them with the appropriate http method that implies that a side-effect will occur e.g. DELETE would be good in this case. By way of the http spec, responses to http DELETE requests shouldn’t be cached.

Answer (score 1):

Had a very similar problem with a corn API route and fixed it with

```
export const revalidate = 0;
```

in the route.js file